# String to Numeric conversion and group separator

Tags: c#, parsing, cultureinfo

When I try to convert a string to a numeric value with Parse or TryParse or Convert.ChangeType, I can't manage de thousand separator as it is defined in the system:

if I enter :

```
var d = double.Parse("1,234", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

it does not return 1234.

If I want to use the group separator, I must type :

```
var d = double.Parse("1,234", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

This time, the result is that one expected.

But, I don't want to force the use of the thousand separator, I want use it only if the system specify it in the globalization settings. Is there a way to know if the separator is used (I know that I can read the group separator in `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator`)

Cheers
Loic

Answer (score 2):

Having `Number` (which includes `AllowThousands`) doesn't *demand* a comma - it simply *allows* it. So you could use `Number` with or without the comma. Or use `Any` or `AllowThousands`.

Note that "comma" is swappable with "thousands separator" - i.e. in some of Eurupe it may vary (period etc). If you **mean** "comma is thousands" then use a fixed culture (such as `InvariantCulture`).

Comment: I'm agree.
But my problem is (assert that culture is 'fr-FR' and thousand separator is a space character), why :
The following line works :
double d = (double)Convert.ChangeType("1 234", typeof (double), _culture);

While the following line throws a format exception ?
int i = (int)Convert.ChangeType("1 234", typeof (int), _culture);

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the second line you use

```
var d = double.Parse("1,234", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

as it will correctly convert 1234 as well as 1,234 and it should cover 1.234 on systems that use '.' as the group separator

Comment: Yes, but in fact, I want to use the Convert.ChangeType function in order to make a generic string to numeric converter, and provide it as a string extension. But Convert.ChangeType has no overload with NumberStyles parameter. It just allows an IFormatProvider parameter.

And by the way, what I don't understand is why the defaut setting for Parse does not meet my system international settings, where use of group separator is setted.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse user input using `CurrentCulture` and not `CurrentUICulture`.

The property `CurrentUICulture` refers to the language on which the user interface is displayed and `CurrentCulture` to the current locale specified in Windows. This way a user working with an application that provides a user interface translated to english (`CurrentUICulture`) can still view/enter, for example, dates and numbers formatted as the locale that he set in Windows (`CurrentCulture`).

Comment: Hello, thank' s for your help.

My application enables the user to change the language as run time (we are providing 7 differents languages). We changes the CurrentUICulture and the CurrentCulture when the user selects a language. We want the user view / enter dates and numbers as the selected language, and not as the locale set in the system.